# Enabling Firewall for Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have an API which is deployed in GKE and exposed via Cloud Endpoints with ESPv2. I have secured the API using API key as of now and its available via internet. Is there any possible way I can apply some firewall rules that the endpoint is available only from a certain network or range of IPs ?

Comment: Where is deployed Cloud Endpoint with ESPv2? On you GKE cluster? if so, how do you expose it, with a load balancer?

Comment: Yes its on GKE and exposed via load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an [ingress with a global HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) in front of your ESPv2 service.

Then, you can activate [Cloud Armor and set policies to filter the IPs](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview) and ranges that you want